# how to send form input to ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to let a user enter an id, then retrieve the attribute with that id. If i'm just using the serial generated by default in a ruby attribute, how do I do this? I'm finding out that I can't have a form  that says

```
  <%= form_tag(guidelines_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <td><%= label_tag(:seeChildren, "See Immediate Children")%></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag :seeChildren, params[:seeChildren], placeholder: "Enter ID" %></td>
  <td><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></td>
  <% end %>
```

app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb has

```
    def index
    if params[:invsearch]
      @guidelines = Guideline.invsearch(params[:invsearch]).all
    elsif params[:progsearch]
      @guidelines = Guideline.progsearch(params[:progsearch]).all
    elsif params[:investor].present? && params[:program_code].present?
      @guidelines = Guideline.invprogsearch(params).all
    elsif params[:client].present? && params[:program_code].present?
      @guidelines = Guideline.cliprogsearch(params).all
    elsif params[:seeChildren]
      @guidelines = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])
    elsif params[:seeParent]
        @guidelines = Guideline.seeParent(params[:seeParent]).all
    else
      @guidelines = Guideline.all
    end
  end
```

Basically there are several different queries that can run, and they all work fine.

Don't worry about what children is in my app, I'm just trying to figure out how to retrieve attribute(s) with user supplied params.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling Guideline to find a `:seeChildren` and that's wrong.
This should be what you want:

```
@guidelines = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])
```

Comment: this still doesn't work. I get a no method error for trying to render index. Would you like to see the whole index controller?

Comment: What method is missing? I'm assuming that you are using Rails

Comment: NoMethodError in Guidelines#index is the error I get. Full index has been added to the original post

Comment: You should post the entire error message, the most important part is the line and the name of the missing method; without them we can't help you much more...